# C# string в array data

Tags: c#, массивы, строки

Мне нужна помощь в правке кода. У меня есть код конвертирующий строку в **hex**:

```
private void convert_bnt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    byte[] ba = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(text_input_Box.Text);
    hex = BitConverter.ToString(ba).Replace("-", " ");
    text_result_Box.Text = hex;

}
```

**На выходе выходит, что-то типа такого:**

```
FB E2 F3 E0 EA
```

**А желаемый результат такой:**

```
0xFBt
0xE2t 
0xF3t
0xE0t
0xEAt
```

Можете помочь мне в этом?

### UPD

Нашёл другой код и сделал нужные правки

```
private static string ConvertToHex(byte[] bytes)
{
    var builder = new StringBuilder();

    var hexCharacters = new[] { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' };

    for (var i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
    {
        int firstValue = (bytes[i] >> 4) & 0x0F;
        int secondValue = bytes[i] & 0x0F;

        char firstCharacter = hexCharacters[firstValue];
        char secondCharacter = hexCharacters[secondValue];

        builder.Append("0x");
        builder.Append(firstCharacter);
        builder.Append(secondCharacter);
        builder.Append('t');
        builder.Append(' ');
    }

    return builder.ToString().Trim(' ');
}
```

### Метод вызываю так:

```
text_result_Box.Text = ConvertToHex(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text_input_Box.Text));
```

### Результат

```
0x74t 0x65t 0x73t 0x74t
```

**Нужно лишь как-то сделать это в столбик**

```
0x74t 
0x65t 
0x73t 
0x74t
```

Comment: Таким - это каким? Массивом строк? Массивом байт? Форматированным выводом в консоль?

Comment: результат выводим в textbox, так, как это WinForms

Comment: Вместо пробела добавьте перевод строки `System.Environment.NewLine`.

Comment: спасибо, всё отлично, что-то я совсем заработался...

Comment: Не нужно добавлять решение в вопрос, решение надо постить отдельно. Откачу вопрос, добавьте решение